# azure devops : Create automatice branch

Tags: events, git-branch, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a git repository in azure devops.
it is possible auto create a new branch when a task in my work items changed status to "Todo"?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no out-box-method in Azure DevOps can auto create a new branch when a work item change to Todo.

To achieve youre requirements, you need to use other workflow tools to customize the workflow(e.g. Azure Logic APP , Power Automate).

You can set the trigger as work item update. Then you can use the Rest API to auto create a new branch: [Initial commit (Create a new branch)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#initial-commit-(create-a-new-branch))

Here is an example:

[image]